# Git commit logger for daily stand-up meeting

Tags: bash, git

At work, my team hosts a daily standup, in which we discuss what we're working on, what we did the day before and any potential blockers for future development.

I thought as a fun little side project that I would write a script in bash to go through each directory in my `/dev/` folder and get all commits from the previous day.

We use Git for the most part, but I do have one or two repositories still under a different source control system. This code is to mitigate that problem `2>> /dev/null;`.

Here is the code:

```
gitUsername="userNameHere"
echo "Here are yesterday's commits:"

for dir in ./*/ ;
    do (cd "$dir"; git log --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cD) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --since yesterday --author $gitUsername} 2>> /dev/null;);
done;

echo "That's everything."
```

I have never written anything in bash before, so any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Also, just a side note in case anybody is interested, we don't read commits to measure workload, I am printing them more as a reminder of the things I was working on the day before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much much much much better way of doing this is:

`find . -type f -exec git --no-pager log --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cD) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --since yesterday {} --author $gitUsername \;`

And a cleaner way to write long statements it to add '\' to break into new lines.

```
find . -type f \
-exec git --no-pager log --pretty=format: \
'%Cred%h%Creset -%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cD) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' \
--since yesterday {} \
--author "${gitUsername}" \;
```

This way, 7 lines are written as 1 and to stdout.

- --no-pager returns everything to your terminal stdout instead your editor.
- `find .` says which directory to search in, so a `for` loop may be useful to only search desired directories
- Also, explicitly defining the desired dirs will remove the need to redirect to stderr and when useful errors are displayed, will be meaningful to you.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

https://www.golinuxcloud.com/find-exec-multiple-commands-examples-unix/

Comment: I like this approach, thanks! The only one I don't agree with is the third point. I want this to be dynamic as I clone or remove a repository maybe once every week or two, so therefore don't want to have to keep a list.

Comment: Then changing the `find .` directory to the larger directory which stores all of your git repositories will do what you desire.